# Java: TCP Encryption, SSL and Netty

Tags: java, encryption, ssl, tcp, netty

Ok so I have a peer to peer (client/server on one host) setup (over a local LAN), this is using Netty, a Java networking framework. I use raw TCP/IP (as in, no HTTP) for communication and transfers.

Currently all data is transferred in "plain-text" and i'm starting the process of securing such transmitted data.

I've had a good read of types of encryption/practices etc (but probably only touched the surface and its melting my brain already)

Netty includes a SSL implemntation, heres some links to hopefully better explain myself:

http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html

Inside "SecureChatTrustManagerFactory" there are 2 methods:

```
          public void checkClientTrusted(
                  X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
              // Always trust - it is an example.
              // You should do something in the real world.
              // You will reach here only if you enabled client certificate auth,
              // as described in SecureChatSslContextFactory.
              System.err.println(
                      "UNKNOWN CLIENT CERTIFICATE: " + chain[0].getSubjectDN());
          }

          public void checkServerTrusted(
                 X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
             // Always trust - it is an example.
              // You should do something in the real world.
              System.err.println(
                      "UNKNOWN SERVER CERTIFICATE: " + chain[0].getSubjectDN());
          }
```

"SecureChatKeyStore" contains a hard coded certificate from what I can see.

So my questions are:

- Do I need to generate a certificate?
- if so, each time the application is run?
- if so, per client?
- if so, is this certification passed between client and server?
- if so, how is it done securely?

I'm not entirely sure where to start.
From what I can see the Netty implementation is saying "Here's the basis of creating secure connections, but we have left out the part that actually makes them secure/authenticated".

Any other pointers/tips I should know about?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've read a lot of stuff (on the web) to do with encryption, authentication, signing very quickly.. not all that has sunk in really, do to the amount there is. I'm not sure I have the time to go into depth, especially when its half implemented already in Netty; i'm mainly looking for that final bit (the certificate part)

Comment: It's not clear how you're going to establish trust between the peers. That seems to be the main missing element in your system.

Comment: @Bruno, I think that is right. I was first looking at public/private key encryption then transitioned over to securing the whole transmitting process, rather than just sending encrypted data over an insecure connection (is that right?). I think this is where I need the help.

Comment: It sounds like you were looking at message-level security whereas you're now looking at transport-level security. Either way, you should read about PKI (and/or Web-of-Trust/PGP) and identity management.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there is a difference between application security and transport link security. I think you are aiming for the last one as you mainly mention encryption. Encryption offers confidentiallity from eavesdroppers. Furhermore, as SSL also incorporates message authentication code, it will also offer protection of a third party altering packets during transit. It does not provide any protection of messages once received.

As you may have noticed on the internet for HTTPS connections, you will need at least a server certificate. This certificate can remain static, although it should contain an expiry date at which time you should replace the certificate. The server certificate should be trusted by the client (e.g. by embedding it as a resource). You can also use SSL with client authentication, but that means you need to have ample security measures to keep the private key on the client safe.

It's probably best to start off with a "self-signed" server certificate only. Thats the one you need to trust in the `checkServerTrusted` method. Basically, the chain is simply that one certificate.

Comment: Note that what you need client authentication to authenticate the client, in other words, although this will protect messages in transit, server authentication alone means anybody can be the client, at least at transport protocol level (web clients normally use a username/password or cookies to add application level authentication for the client, of course).